# NSOutlineView drag image

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop, nsoutlineview, nsdragginginfo, nsdraggingitem

I want to change the image used when I drag an item from a view- and datasource-based `NSOutlineView`, but can't seem to find a hook.  I've tried modifying

```
- (void)dragImage:(NSImage *)anImage at:(NSPoint)viewLocation offset:(NSSize)initialOffset event:(NSEvent *)event pasteboard:(NSPasteboard *)pboard source:(id)sourceObj slideBack:(BOOL)slideFlag
```

in the rowViews, in the tableCellViews, and in a subclass of `NSOutlineView` itself, but to no avail.

Does anyone know where the default image (it's obviously taken from the tableCellView's image and textfield) is coming from?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the image is obtained from NSTableCellView.  So the hook is to override -(NSArray *)draggingImageComponents in a subclass of that.

Answer (score 0):

It's slightly awkward:
From your [data source](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSTableDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004178) you can set the images on the `NSDraggingSession` instance you're passed via parameger e.g. to `tableView:draggingSession:willBeginAtPoint:forRowIndexes:`.

You can then use the [`enumerateDraggingItemsWithOptions:forView:classes:searchOptions:usingBlock:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSDraggingSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDraggingSession/enumerateDraggingItemsWithOptions%3aforView%3aclasses%3asearchOptions%3ausingBlock%3a) method on the `NSDraggingSession` instance to change the actual drag images of your `NSDraggingItems`:

```
   [session enumerateDraggingItemsWithOptions:NSDraggingItemEnumerationConcurrent
                                      forView:tableView
                                      classes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSPasteboardItem class]]
                                searchOptions:nil
                                   usingBlock:^(NSDraggingItem *draggingItem, NSInteger index, BOOL *stop)
    {
       [draggingItem setDraggingFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, myWidth, myHeight)
                             contents:myFunkyDragImage];
    }];
```

Comment: for the records : dont use NSMakeRect(0, 0, myWidth, myHeight)  the frame is  !! don't ever try to use either session.dragginglocation

Comment: @Xav ?? Why wouldn't you? Works like a breeze in our code base across numerous OS versions